# How do I update a key field on insert for SQL Server (Siebel table S_CAMP_CON)

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers, siebel

I need help on writing a trigger in SQL Server to be used in Siebel:

- The system field ROW_ID has to be unique (key)
- When the field INSERT_CD and CAMP_WAVE_ID is null then ROW_ID must be generated (see below).
- If not, leave ROW_ID as is.
- ROW_ID is a key field of varchar(15).

The following statement generates the perfect key/row id:

```
select substring(replace (CAST (newid() as varchar(36)),'-',''),1,15)
```

I need help on writing a SQL Server 2005 trigger to generate this key.

Comment: Here is a hint from Oracle:

create trigger test_trigger
before insert on S_CAMP_CON
for each row
begin
select test_seq.nextval into :new.ROW_ID from dual;
end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way we did it. We setup OBIEE to generate a ROW_ID that is unique for the current load and hence why the WHERE clause can get the record to be updated.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'S_CAMP_CON_Direct_Load_ROW_ID' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER S_CAMP_CON_Direct_Load_ROW_ID
GO
CREATE TRIGGER S_CAMP_CON_Direct_Load_ROW_ID
ON S_CAMP_CON FOR INSERT
AS

UPDATE S_CAMP_CON
    SET ROW_ID = (select substring(replace (CAST (newid() as varchar(36)),'-',''),1,15))
   WHERE S_CAMP_CON.ROW_ID IN
   (SELECT ROW_ID FROM inserted WHERE INSERT_CD = 'Direct Load')
```

But we are concerned by the **uniqueness of ROW_ID** since we are using a substring.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest not to modify ROW_ID. Use a different column, maybe add your own extension column, but don't modify (or try to set yourself) ROW_ID. Leave it at the value that  Siebel puts in there.

You must not modify any of the system columns (Type "System", check in Tools, in Table > Columns)

Comment: Using direct insert for campaing loading bypasses the Siebel Data Layer since OBIEE directly inserts records into S_CAMP_CON.